# Is it possible to run 2 Where Clauses for Different Columns? Not sure how to set up this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find products that were bought outside of working hours (9-5). I'm trying to find all of the times that products were bought outside of the 9-5 working hours. However, yellow shirts can be purchased from 7 AM to 5 PM. I'm not sure how to do 2 Where Clauses for that.

There are 100 products. Here is an example:

```
Product            Time_Purchased 

Toothbrush           8:00 AM 
Yellow Shirt         7:00 AM 
Orange Sweatshirt    9:00 AM 
Tablet Decoration    10:00 AM 
Yellow Shirt         6:00 AM
```

With this example, the output for Yellow Shirts should not include the 8 AM Time, but it should include the 6 AM.

This is the code I tried running:

```
PROC SQL 
Select * FROM Example 
Where (Time_Purchased NOT BETWEEN 32400 AND 61200) 
AND Product = 'Yellow Shirt' AND Time_Purchased <25200
quit;
```

When I run this code, I only get Yellow Shirts purchased before 7:30 and it ignores all of the other products. I'm not sure how to edit the code to show all of the products other than yellow shirts that were purchased outside of 9-5 and the yellow shirts that were purchased outside of 7:30-5 using Where statements.

Comment: Use an OR: `(time between 9am to 5pm AND product != 'Yellow Shirt') or (time between 7am to 5pm AND product = 'Yellow Shirt')`

Comment: The `Yellow Shirt` product doesn't have purchase at 8 AM in your data example yet you said _"With this example, the output for Yellow Shirts should not include the 8 AM Time"_. What is the expected result? What `products` should be returned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `OR` operator to seperate the 2 conditions in your query. What the `OR` operator does is return a result if any of the `WHERE` conditions is true. In your case this would be either 1) when the product is not a yellow shirt and is sold between 9-5 or 2) when the product is a yellow shirt and is sold between 7-5. The query would be similar to the one below:

```
PROC SQL 
SELECT * FROM Example 
WHERE Time_Purchased BETWEEN 25200 AND 61200 AND Product = 'Yellow Shirt' 
OR Time_Purchased BETWEEN 32400 AND 61200 AND Product != 'Yellow Shirt' 
QUIT;
```

This should work for you.